# CSS Add content property which will display above/under the table cell

Tags: html, css

I want to create board for sea battle. I need to show number above and under table cell using content property. I have no ideas what style it is necessary to add.

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: what is this "number" keyword you're using? also `td:do something` is not a valid css selector

Comment: you need to post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to explain what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I'm really trying to figure out what you mean exactly, but no success here :-D

Could you provide some virtual material to understand what you're trying to accomplish? I think you mean BattleShip, or am I wrong here?

When that's the case I think you'd like to calculate from some (active) starting point, right? And after moving the cursor from that point (which you can achieve with the :active condition) up and down or left and right what shows the distance count (1,2,3 etc points) displayed in the cell you're hovering on? Or do the upper and lower cells 'move' visual along with the mouse cursor?

Maybe it's possible with CSS, but with javascript it will be a lot easier I think